# How to remove DataTable rows and keep pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I remove DataTables rows and keep pagination!
I use `datatable.clear()` but this one  not keep pagination;

Comment: What do you mean by "keep pagination"? It could mean a number of different things. Can you clarify with some examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var table = $('#yourtableId').DataTable();
table.rows().remove().draw();
```

Comment: this one does not keep the pagination

Comment: I don't think it's possible to keep pagination without having any row